# Using AWS CLI to list SSO User/group assigned to a permission set

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get information about which User/group (within AWS accounts) is assigned to each permission set using AWS CLI.

In the AWS UI, this information is displayed here: (two black boxes on the bottom)
[image]

In CLI, using SSO-admin I tried using `list-accounts-for-provisioned-permission-set` and `list-permission-sets-provisioned-to-account` but this did not get me this information.

I also tried `list-account-assignments` and got a "PrincipalId" for a permission set but I'm not sure if this refers to the "User/group" from the picture above. Is there anywhere I could see which PrincipalId belongs to each user/group?

Is there a way to access this information with AWS CLI?

UPDATE: I found some documentation regarding the "PrincipalId" from `list-account-assignments`:

> An identifier for an object in Amazon Web Services SSO, such as a user or group. PrincipalIds are GUIDs (For example, f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6). For more information about PrincipalIds in Amazon Web Services SSO, see the Amazon Web Services SSO Identity Store API Reference .

From the [reference above](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/IdentityStoreAPIReference/welcome.html) I found the following:

> The scope of these API operations is currently limited to only this functionality and does not include generic operations, such as listing all users or groups in the AWS SSO Identity Store.

Based on this I'm guessing that what I'm trying to do is currently impossible.

Comment: Hey, Did you try ```aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name example_user_name``` ,as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-groups-for-user.html

Comment: @RoyLevy That list IAM groups which are separate from SSO groups.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you were trying to receive IAM list. The only thing I  found about SSO listing is ```list-permission-sets``` which states it lists all of the permissions in SSO instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sso-admin/list-permission-sets.html

Comment: Yes, that lists the permission sets but not any other information about them.

Comment: So you are getting Principals from the ```list-account-assignments``` but not the account id's? The structure of the API response should consist of them both in the same hierarchy, so if you are not getting them also something may be wrong with the request.

Comment: I get the account ID (which is required to run the command in the first place). The account ID I get in the output is from the AWS account which is selected in the picture I posted. I want the user/group information.

Comment: Just saw your update to the post - Really seems like there is no way to do it from CLI as they also said that "Future updates to AWS SSO Identity Store APIs, including additions for creation and modification of users and groups, will be documented in this reference as they are released." So it can be concluded that if creation and modification will be added there will also be listing of the groups and users.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible officially :(
Here's the proof – https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/109
It's being anticipated by many users for months, but still unresolved.

Though, in the middle of comments you can find an *unofficial* way to do it with a limit, only a maximum of 50 results can be returned this way - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/109#issuecomment-1031766572

Comment: Thanks for the issue link. Didn't know it was widely anticipated.

Comment: The GitHub links from this answer are talking about listing users, whereas the parent is looking for a way to see both users and groups assigned/mapped to permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

There's no native feature currently with the cli. However, there's a custom solution built for that to automatically generate the report and list out all users and groups' associated permission sets + AWS/customer-managed/inline policies

https://github.com/ooiyeefei/aws-iam-identity-center-permission-policies-analyzer